# Pandas can't read my csv one desktop, works fine on laptop

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this quite big CSV, almost 10GB in size. 
I want to read it in and do some Data Science work on it. 
On my company laptop, this works just fine. Data gets read in, and I can do anything to it I want. 
Because of the complexity of algorithms and the size of the data, this take quite a while on my company laptop, although this is a quite modern i7, 16GB machine.

I figured my desktop would run this much faster, as it has 8 cores & 16 threads, also 16GB of memory but most of all: a dedicated GPU, which my company laptop doesn't have. 
When I run the exact same script on my desktop however, it doesn't work! The frustrating thing is: I don't get any error messages, it just doesn't seem to do anything.

Things I tried:

- Include a print statement in the code after reading in the data, so I know when it is done reading the csv.
- Read in only 10 rows of data. This to single out it just runs really long on the big dataset.
- Save the dataset as utf-8 and tell Pandas to read the dataset as utf-8.
- Just let it run for like 4-5 hours

None of the above has helped.
Who has got the magic answer to this?

```
float_data = pd.read_csv("../train10.csv", encoding="utf-8", sep=',', dtype={"signal": np.float32, "seconds": np.float32})

float_data = float_data.values
print("Data loaded")
```

Comment: Is your script just taking a long time? or it terminate running the script?

Comment: Is there difference in python installations? Maybe 32bit python vs 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, actually. I noticed the debug function didn't work and then found that my python configuration was incorrect. Now it reads my data just fine. Case closed.